# How to debug views_handler_field_node_revision handler?

Tags: views, debugging

I believe I have updated some of my modules, then the following debug message pop on the calendar page. Does anyone know what is this message and how to solve it?

> Debug:
>
> > 'Handler views_handler_field_node_revision tried to add
> >     additional_field nid but node could not be added!'
>
> in views_handler_field->add_additional_fields() (line 142 of
>   /public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field.inc).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when the "Content revision: Title" field on my view was set to "Link this field to the original piece of content" however it wasn't using the relationship to the content.

I set it to use the "Content revision: Content" which fixed the link and the error.

I think this error is displayed with problems regarding a node_revision view and an error in the relationship, as Nels mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

When I get this error, it's because I have a bad Relationship in the View creating a page.

For instance, I want to display the title of a referenced piece of content, but the relationship is either not setup or incorrect.

In my case, the title I want is actually referenced from a piece of content that is referenced from a field on the Entity type is displaying.  I needed to add a second Relationship (using the first Relationship).

Hope that helps someone.