# Debug: 'Handler views_handler_field_node_revision node could not be added!'

Tags: views

[image]i have a problem when i try to create a task on ERPAL, i have this message

Task toolerp has been created.
   Debug:
   'Handler views_handler_field_node_revision tried to add additional_field language but    node could not be added!'
   in views_handler_field->add_additional_fields() (line 142 of   /var/www/vhosts/.../erpal/profiles/erpal/modules/contrib/views/handlers/views_handler_field.inc).

does any body have a hint ?

Thanks

Comment: Check this other thread. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104781/debug-handler-views-handler-field-node-revision . Looks like the same problem.

Comment: Hi rtome,
yes i did check that but didn't understand the solution, in the forum comment rules it's written "do no ask for explaination" so i've started a new post, i don't know if this is ok with rules.

Comment: Not sure of what the right etiquette is either. Still you problem is with views, and that other thread hits on some view relationship being wrong. Have you checked your view definition ? Does it preview ok in your views admin ?

Comment: I'm working with ERPAL (CRM disribution), where can i see this view in some modules ?

Comment: If you tried solution there and have new question, tell us how you tried and what you don't understand. That's OK. If it's the same question and you do not know what to do with the answer at all, you can add bounty and describe you want more friendly / basic explanation.

Comment: Hello Molot, i have the same problem but not on the Drupal basic distribution, in fact i'm using the ERPAL CRM tool that's why i can not apply the solution. I'm searching a solution for ERPAL tool views. Thank you!